# Why won't Express.js properly read POST parameters?

Tags: node.js, http-post, express

HEre's my POST:

```
account_id  1231
limit   3
ordertype   limit
quantity    1
symbol  USDJPY
transaction_type    buy
```

In my code, I have:

```
 var account_id = req.param('account_id', null);
  var symbol_pair = req.param('symbol', null);
  var transaction_type = req.param('transaction_type', null);
  var order_type = req.param('ordertype', null);
  var amount = req.param('amount', null);
  var limit = req.param('limit', null);

console.log(account_id + " | " + symbol_pair + " | " + transaction_type + " | " + order_type + " | " + amount + " | " + limit);return;
```

But for some reason `ordertype` comes back `market`. Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: It's hard to answer a question like this. Maybe you forgot an underscore (order_type vs ordertype)? You could just console.log( req.params ) to see what params you have available.

Comment: A lot more information is needed. Could you show us the code that actually does the POST? Please try @Pickels' suggestion of logging `req.params`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make sure you have `app.use(express.bodyParser());` and try with `req.body.account_id` (and similar style for each one)

http://expressjs.com/guide.html#http-methods

Answer (score 0):

You are defining order_type and then trying to get it back with ordertype. Don't forget your: underscore!

Comment: That's not true, the var is called `order_type` but the `req.param` call is using `'ordertype'`.